ChromeOS のコンテナ環境で apt download cros-im を実行すると E: Unable to locate package cros-im が表示される。
実行環境
ChromeOSのcrostini上のUbuntu 22.04
croshを使用
期待値
cros-imをダウンロードしたい。
再現手順

CTRL+ALT+Tを押して Chromeシェル (crosh) に入り、デフォルトのterminaVM を入力する。

vmc start termina


デフォルトのpenguinコンテナの名前を変更する。

lxc stop penguin --force
lxc rename penguin debian


ubuntuという名前の新しい Ubuntu コンテナを作成する。

lxc launch ubuntu:24.04 ubuntu


LXDプロジェクトがLinuxContainersプロジェクトから分割された結果、状況は少し不安定になっている。Ubuntuイメージファイルにアクセスできない場合は、3. を実行する前に次のコマンドを実行しよう。

lxc remote set-url images https://images.lxd.canonical.com/


ubuntuコンテナを起動する。

lxc start ubuntu


新しいコンテナに入ると、自動的にrootになる。

lxc exec ubuntu -- bash


デフォルトのUbuntuユーザーのグループ メンバーシップを取得し、ユーザーを削除する。
後で使用する小さなスクリプトを作成し、ユーザー名をすべてのデフォルトの Ubuntu グループに追加してから、デフォルトのubuntuユーザーを削除する。

groups ubuntu >update-groups
sed -i 'y/ /,/; s/ubuntu,:,ubuntu,/sudo usermod -aG /; s/$/ \$USER/' update-groups
killall -u ubuntu
userdel -r ubuntu
sed -i '/^ubuntu/d' /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users


配布が最新であることを確認する。
Google の Crostini 固有のパッケージをインストールする準備として、まず Ubuntu を最新の状態にする。

apt update
apt upgrade


Crostini サポートパッケージを手動でインストールする。

echo "deb https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages bookworm main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cros.list
if [ -f /dev/.cros_milestone ]; then sudo sed -i "s?packages?packages/$(cat /dev/.cros_milestone)?" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cros.list; fi
apt update #公開鍵が利用できないという旨のエラーが出現する。NO_PUBKEY XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXと出てくるがそれが公開鍵。XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXを登録する。


公開鍵を登録する。apt updateで公開鍵が利用できないという旨のエラーが出現する。
NO_PUBKEY XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXと出てくるがそれが公開鍵。XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXを登録する。

wget -O - https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/128/dists/bookworm/Release.gpg | gpg --dearmor > /usr/share/keyrings/cros-packages-archive-keyring.gpg # 公開鍵をファイルに保存し、リポジトリ設定に追加する。
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
nano ubuntu.source # deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cros-packages-archive-keyring.gpg] https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/128 bookworm main を追記する。
apt update


packagekit.serviceとunattended-upgrades.serviceを再起動する。

systemctl restart packagekit.service
systemctl restart unattended-upgrades.service
apt upgrade


インストール用にCrostiniパッケージを準備する。
cros-ui-configパッケージのインストールの競合に対する回避策が必要。
元の回避策は参照用に保持される。
まず修正してcros-imをインストールする。

apt download cros-im # E: Unable to locate package cros-im が出現する。

参考リンク
ChromeOS のコンテナ環境で apt update を実行するとGPG error などが表示される
https://www.reddit.com/r/Crostini/wiki/howto/run-ubuntu/?rdt=42779#wiki_workaround_for_chrome_os_m107.2B_.28cros-ui-config_0.15_all.deb.29
